# JS: when exactly to use a Promise other than for network requests?

Tags: javascript

Are Promises only used when requests are made?

```
  function sync1() {
      console.log("sync1");
  }
  function sync2() {
      console.log("sync2")
  }
  sync1();
  sync2();
```

This will always output "sync1" followed by "sync2" so it'd be pointless to do this, right? :

```
  function sync1() {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
          console.log("sync1");
          resolve(true);
     })
  }
  function sync2() {
      console.log("sync2")
  }
  sync1();
  sync2();
```

I understand that when making `fetch` requests, this can come into play if you need to wait for the response like this:

```
  function sync1() {
      // ensure this request 
      return fetch('/testing');
  }
  function sync2() {
      console.log("sync2")
  }
  sync1().then((resp) => { 
      console.log("I have my response!");
      sync2();
  })
```

But besides network requests where you can return the fetch itself, when else would you need to return a Promise?

Answer (score 1):

Promises can be used for any async operations, not only HTTP calls. For example, reading/writing files. You can start getting acquainted with it from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 0):

I think wherever you want to execute asynchronous code synchronously you can use promises .eg if you want to make  setTimeout synchronous you can use promises. But I guess there is no use case for that